# Will SelectionKey.isWritable return false for socket channel in java nio?

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

If we register `OP_WRITE` on a `SocketChannel`, it seems `selectionKey.isWritable()` method always return TRUE.
Will there be any specific scenario that it returns FALSE for a socket channel?

Comment: It is true unless the socket send buffer is full, which only happens if the receiver's receive buffer is full.

Comment: Can't imagine why this was downvoted.